# Which OpenJDK11 components are dependent on MuJS on Alpine Linux?

Tags: alpine-linux, openjdk-11

MuJS is a Javascript interpreter, which doesn't exist in the list of packages for Alpine linux (latest release 3.14 as of now). However, when one installs an [OpenJDK11 package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk11-jre&branch=v3.14&repo=&arch=x86_64&maintainer=) on Alpine, as shown below, it does seem to get picked up by security scanning tools:

```
apk add openjdk11-jre
```

Where can I find the list of all Linux components that get bundled/ installed along with the installation of OpenJDK11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find the list of all Linux components that get bundled/ installed along with the installation of OpenJDK11?

For the list of dependent packages that are installed along with `openjdk11-jre`, you can refer to the [package page](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.14/community/x86_64/openjdk11-jre). You could also see them when installing the package with `apk`.

To get the list of installed java modules, run: `java --list-modules`.

To get the complete list of files that are installed with this package and its dependent packages, you could dump the list of all files of the container:

```
sudo docker export <container-id> | tar tfv - > out.txt
```

Then, do the same for the vanilla Alpine 3.14 image, and compare the outputs.    You can see the diff [here](https://pastebin.com/NT2rZ0w1).

> However, when one installs an OpenJDK11 package on Alpine, as shown below, it does seem to get picked up by security scanning tools.

This is most likely a false positive, based on available evidence:

- As you've noted, there's no MuJS dependency listed, and no MuJS package is available in the Alpine repositories ([package name search](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=*mujs*&branch=v3.14), [content search](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=*mujs*&path=&name=&branch=v3.14))
- None of the MuJS files could be found on the container: `mujs` executable, `libmujs.a`, `libmujs.so` or any of the [source files](https://github.com/ccxvii/mujs)
- In theory, if part of the OpenJDK distribution, MuJS could be statically linked into one of the libraries and executables. So just in case, I searched the OpenJDK 11 github mirror for `mujs`, which gave [0 results](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/search?q=mujs)
- Similar issue was previously posted on the OpenJDK mailing list, but not answered:
  https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2019-June/005069.html

My suggestion is to contact the security scan tool vendor and report this issue as a potential false positive.